# Nginx + spring not serving static files for suddomain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nginx

I'm migrating a spring application to another server that uses nginx.
The application needs to be served as subdomain but only the *.jsp and *.html files are showing.

The static files are not founded because it's been requested as if the application was deployed after the domain like so (domain.com.br:8765/subdomain/)

Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.domain.com.br;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://domain.com.br:8765/subdomain/;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
            proxy_pass              $scheme://domain.com.br:8765/$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            expires 30d;
    }
}
```

Spring log

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/subdomain/subdomain/resources/css/base.css]
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/subdomain/subdomain/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js]
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/subdomain/subdomain/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.js]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having this same problem but haven't found my way around it. Did you?
I'm stuck trying to remap the request to the appropriate path.